# SQLite: LIMIT values depending on a condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given the following table:

```
ID   A    B
-----------
1    6    5
2    3    2
3    5    1
4    5    5
5    9    8
6    1    7
```

I need to `SELECT` the first X rows that met the condition (A - B) > 0
So it cannot be a:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE (A - B) > 0
```

Otherwise I'd get row with ID 5, while I would like to STOP on row 3.

Is it possible to write a condition in the LIMIT statement?
Some like:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE LIMIT (A - B) > 0
```

How can I do? Are there any alternatives?

Note: when I wrote "the first X rows" I mean an ascending ordering on ID.

UPDATE:
I did not explain myself correctly, sorry. **I don't know the X value.**
I said X as unknown variable, depending on table.
I rephrase the requirement:

> I need to select all the rows (starting from ID 1) until the condition (A
>   - B) > 0 is not met.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY ID LIMIT x` at the end, where x is an integer value.

Comment: Are there any gaps in the id values? Or are they always going to be sequential?

Comment: @Shawn: sequential, it's an autogenerated incremental ID

Comment: Unless it's generated by something outside of sqlite, that doesn't mean there's no gaps. `rowid`/`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` values can have gaps even when using `AUTOINCREMENT` mode, rows can be deleted, etc. Anyways, added a variation to my answer to handle both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID < (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM TABLE WHERE (A - B) <= 0) ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Sorry I did not explain myself correctly. I've updated the description

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful if there are no rows that match the ending condition.

Here is a method that always works:

```
SELECT t.ID
FROM test t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(id) as min_id
      FROM test
      WHERE A <= B
     ) tt
WHERE t.id < tt.min_id OR tt.min_id IS NULL;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b70fcf8ca057737435d25b9b90c8ce19) is a db<>fiddle.  (It happens to use MySQL; that is because table creation in SQLite doesn't appear to be working.)

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/14e20/1)

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (A - B) > 0 LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Sorry I did not explain myself correctly. I've updated the description

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a basic gaps and islands problem where you want to find only the first island. That sort of thing is easy to solve using the window functions added in sqlite 3.25 (And this answer thus won't work with older versions).

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a INTEGER, b INTEGER);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,6,5);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,3,2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(3,5,1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(4,5,5);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(5,9,8);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(6,1,7);
```

this query:

```
WITH islands AS
  (SELECT id, a, b
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a - b > 0 ORDER BY id) AS isle_rn
   FROM test)
SELECT id, a, b
FROM islands
WHERE id = isle_rn AND a - b > 0
ORDER BY id;
```

produces

```
id          a           b         
----------  ----------  ----------
1           6           5         
2           3           2         
3           5           1
```

Basically, it splits the table up into two partitions - those where `a - b > 0` is true, and those where it's false. Each partition is sorted by `id`, and each row is then numbered. Finally, only the rows where that number is equal to `id` are returned - the first row where the condition is false will cause all later rows where it's true to have a different id and row number. The extra check that `a - b > 0` is there to catch the case where id 1 is false and no rows should thus be returned.

This does assume that `id` always starts at 1 and has no gaps. If that's not the case, this variation adds a sequential row number that's used instead of `id`:

```
WITH islands AS
  (SELECT id, a, b
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a - b > 0 ORDER BY id) AS isle_rn
   FROM test)
SELECT id, a, b
FROM islands
WHERE isle_rn = rn AND a - b > 0
ORDER BY id;
```